# Pass through mouse event from Custom Control to parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On my Custom Control, a custom button, I want to raise the MouseDown to the parent, after I handle some things with it.
Calling OnMouseDown from the MouseDown handler locks up the program with a System.StackOverflowException at the OnMouseDown line.
Code is shown below.
How can I raise the MouseDown, and MouseUp, to parent?

C#, WinForms, .Net 6.0

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestMouseDown
{
    public partial class TestMouseDownControl : Control
    {
        public TestMouseDownControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MouseDown += TestMouseDownControl_MouseDown;
        }

        private void TestMouseDownControl_MouseDown(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);

            Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), ClientRectangle);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
}

namespace TestMouseDown
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TestMouseDownControl tmdc = new TestMouseDownControl();
            Controls.Add(tmdc);

            tmdc.MouseDown += Tmdc_MouseDown;
        }

        private void Tmdc_MouseDown(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `OnMouseDown(e);` in the `Form.MouseDown` handler, causes a call to `OnMouseDown()` which raises the `Form.MouseDown` event, from where you call `OnMouseDown()` which... -- In the Form, you want to subscribe to the `MouseDown` event of your Custom Control instead

Comment: Sorry, wrong code.  Changed to proper code from the Custom Control.  I put that Custom Control on the form, ran program, clicked on Control.  Same problem, though.  When I try to propagate the MouseDown, it appears to loop as soon as I click on the control.

Comment: Nope, you're still subscribing to the Form's MouseDown event, using a different name for the event handler. Assume the instance of your Custom Control is named `testMouseDownControl1`, you should have `testMouseDownControl1.MouseDown += TestMouseDownControl_MouseDown`. You of course don't call `OnMouseDown(e)` from there -- Not clear what you want to do with that event handler or what overriding `OnPaint()` has to do with anything here

Comment: I need to handle a MouseDown in my control.  Then I need to have it available for the parent when they subscribe to my MouseDown.
How do I send a raise a MouseDown event for the parent to see?
Or am I not subscribing to the MouseDown correctly?

Comment: It depends on what kind of Custom Control you have there. A Custom Control usually inherits from a base Control (e.g., `Button`) or from `Control` itself. In this, just subscribe to its `MouseDown` event as described, since this event is exposed by the Control class. Maybe you have an UserControl instead and you want to expose a public event related to a child Control? Specify what kind of Control you have there

Comment: Allright, I see: you don't have to do anything in your Custom Control, since it derives from `Control`, just subscribe to its MouseDown event in your Form

Comment: It's set up as a "Custom Control (Windows Forms)" when I add a Component to my Project.  I use MouseDown to change some graphics on my custom button.  Then need to make the parent aware of mouse down.  I realize I could raise my own MyMouseDown event.  But is there a way to raise a MouseDown to the parent?

Comment: ah ... so I don't even have to raise it?  It's just available?

Comment: As mentioned, the MouseDown event belongs to the `Control` class; since you inherit from it, the MouseDown event is already available in your Control. Just subscribe to it in your Form -- If you need to add custom behavior, you should override `OnMouseDown()` in your Control, not subscribe to the `MouseDown` event. In the override, you of course call `base.OnMouseDown(e)`, to raise the event for all subscribers

Comment: Nice!  That explains it.  Thank you very much!!